# filter space and equal character for xss prevention

Tags: php, html, xss

I'm trying to scan my site for potential xss flaws.
I'm using a google chrome extension called "HackTab" to do the XSS scanning.
On the report i've got this message:

> The parameter [search] contains a potential Cross Site Scripting flaw
>   in an unquoted HTML attribute. The error occurs because the &space and
>   = characters are not encoded correctly

The url that was used for the request was:

results.html?search=hTeXz"'<>= "<>g7mxZ

and the "PROOF" for the flaw was:

=hTeXz%22%27%3C%3E%3D+%26quot%3B%26lt%3B%26gt%3Bg7mxZ"

the flaw that it found was sanitizied using PHP urlencode function

it looks like it is encoded , but maybe not in the right way , or do you think i should ignore this warning , it's safely encoded?

Comment: The url encoding of a double quote is `%22`, but it was converted to `%26quot%3B` instead., so it was converted to an html entity and then url encoded. What is the surrounding html context? Is it within a url, or html element?

Comment: i'm not sure, i could'nt find the place it was talking about, the string appears several place in the document, in links , pagination, search 
it's a search results page

Comment: I'd expect it to be either the other way round, so url encoded and then html encoded, or html encoded only. Although different placements can require different encodings.